Ubuntu 24.10, kernel 6.11.0 - MIPI camera not working
Please, notice that this question is not like others as the environment I am running is different than other questions I found in AskUbuntu. Other questions in AskUbuntu refer to older Kernel versions.
If I issue on the CLI sudo gst-launch-1.0 icamerasrc ! autovideosink a window open and I can see crystal clear my camera image, meaning the hardware must be sound. I guess the driver is also working correctly? Since the image looks crystal clear and fluid and opens up immediately.
However, if I open Cheese, it does not list any camera. Web browsers such as Google Chrome, Firefox, either would detect any camera.
I am running:

Ubuntu 24.10
6.11.0-9-generic
Used drivers from https://launchpad.net/~oem-solutions-group/+archive/ubuntu/intel-ipu6
Tried also the ipu6 driver from the default repositories, same result.

Some details:
user@gb4:~$ cheese 
[1:11:16.637064724] [20241] ERROR IPAModule ipa_module.cpp:172 Symbol ipaModuleInfo not found
[1:11:16.637087068] [20241] ERROR IPAModule ipa_module.cpp:292 v4l2-compat.so: IPA module has no valid info
[1:11:16.637104149] [20241]  INFO Camera camera_manager.cpp:313 libcamera v0.3.1
** Message: 22:32:54.354: cheese-application.vala:222: Error during camera setup: No device found


user@gb4:~$ sudo dmesg | grep -E "mipi|ipu6"
[   17.602564] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   17.603038] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: Device 0x7d19 (rev: 0x4)
[   17.603063] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: physical base address 0x5230000000
[   17.603065] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: mapped as: 0x000000003ce7bf29
[   17.603169] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPU in secure mode
[   17.603172] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPU secure touch = 0x80000000
[   17.603174] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPU camera mask = 0x0
[   17.615685] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPC reset done
[   17.617635] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: FW version: 20230925
[   17.621850] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: Found supported sensor OVTI02C1:00
[   17.622028] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: Connected 1 cameras
[   17.630844] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: Sending BOOT_LOAD to CSE
[   17.672195] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: Sending AUTHENTICATE_RUN to CSE
[   17.720309] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: CSE authenticate_run done
[   17.720361] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPU6-v4 driver version 1.0
[   18.035921] intel-ipu6-psys intel-ipu6-psys0: pkg_dir entry count:8
[   18.036059] intel-ipu6-psys intel-ipu6-psys0: psys probe minor: 0
[   18.097030] intel-ipu6-isys intel-ipu6-isys0: bind ov02c10 3-0036 nlanes is 2 port is 4
[   18.097378] intel-ipu6-isys intel-ipu6-isys0: All sensor registration completed.


user@gb4:~$ v4l2-ctl --all 
Driver Info:
    Driver name      : v4l2 loopback
    Card type        : Intel MIPI Camera
    Bus info         : platform:v4l2loopback-000
    Driver version   : 6.11.0
    Capabilities     : 0x85200002
        Video Output
        Read/Write
        Streaming
        Extended Pix Format
        Device Capabilities
    Device Caps      : 0x05200002
        Video Output
        Read/Write
        Streaming
        Extended Pix Format
Priority: 2
Video output: 0 (loopback in)
Format Video Capture:
    Width/Height      : 640/480
    Pixel Format      : 'BGR4'
    Field             : None
    Bytes per Line    : 0
    Size Image        : 0
    Colorspace        : Default
    Transfer Function : Default (maps to Rec. 709)
    YCbCr/HSV Encoding: Default (maps to ITU-R 601)
    Quantization      : Default (maps to Full Range)
    Flags             : 
Format Video Output:
    Width/Height      : 640/480
    Pixel Format      : 'BGR4' (32-bit BGRA/X 8-8-8-8)
    Field             : None
    Bytes per Line    : 0
    Size Image        : 0
    Colorspace        : Default
    Transfer Function : Default (maps to Rec. 709)
    YCbCr/HSV Encoding: Default (maps to ITU-R 601)
    Quantization      : Default (maps to Full Range)
    Flags             : 
Streaming Parameters Video Capture:
    Frames per second: 30.000 (30/1)
    Read buffers     : 2
Streaming Parameters Video Output:
    Frames per second: 30.000 (30/1)
    Write buffers    : 2

User Controls

                    keep_format 0x0098f900 (bool)   : default=0 value=0
              sustain_framerate 0x0098f901 (bool)   : default=0 value=0
                        timeout 0x0098f902 (int)    : min=0 max=100000 step=1 default=0 value=0
               timeout_image_io 0x0098f903 (button) : value=0 flags=write-only, execute-on-write


Another:
user@gb4:~$ sudo v4l2loopback-ctl list
OUTPUT          CAPTURE         NAME
/dev/video0     /dev/video0     Intel MIPI Camera


josem@gb4:~$ lscpu 
Architecture:             x86_64
  CPU op-mode(s):         32-bit, 64-bit
  Address sizes:          46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
  Byte Order:             Little Endian
CPU(s):                   22
  On-line CPU(s) list:    0-21
Vendor ID:                GenuineIntel
  Model name:             Intel(R) Core(TM) Ultra 7 155H
    CPU family:           6
    Model:                170
    Thread(s) per core:   2
    Core(s) per socket:   16
    Socket(s):            1
    Stepping:             4
    CPU(s) scaling MHz:   31%
    CPU max MHz:          4800.0000
    CPU min MHz:          400.0000
    BogoMIPS:             5990.40
    Flags:                fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe s
                          yscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf t
                          sc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic
                           movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb intel_ppin ssbd ibrs
                           ibpb stibp ibrs_enhanced tpr_shadow flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rd
                          seed adx smap clflushopt clwb intel_pt sha_ni xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves split_lock_detect user_shstk avx_vnni dtherm
                           ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp hwp_pkg_req hfi vnmi umip pku ospke waitpkg gfni vaes vpclmulqdq 
                          rdpid bus_lock_detect movdiri movdir64b fsrm md_clear serialize arch_lbr ibt flush_l1d arch_capabilities
Virtualization features:  
  Virtualization:         VT-x
Caches (sum of all):      
  L1d:                    544 KiB (14 instances)
  L1i:                    896 KiB (14 instances)
  L2:                     18 MiB (9 instances)
  L3:                     24 MiB (1 instance)
NUMA:                     
  NUMA node(s):           1
  NUMA node0 CPU(s):      0-21
Vulnerabilities:          
  Gather data sampling:   Not affected
  Itlb multihit:          Not affected
  L1tf:                   Not affected
  Mds:                    Not affected
  Meltdown:               Not affected
  Mmio stale data:        Not affected
  Reg file data sampling: Not affected
  Retbleed:               Not affected
  Spec rstack overflow:   Not affected
  Spec store bypass:      Mitigation; Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl
  Spectre v1:             Mitigation; usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization
  Spectre v2:             Mitigation; Enhanced / Automatic IBRS; IBPB conditional; RSB filling; PBRSB-eIBRS Not affected; BHI BHI_DIS_S
  Srbds:                  Not affected
  Tsx async abort:        Not affected


and
josem@gb4:~$ v4l2-ctl --list-devices
ipu6 (PCI:pci:pci0000:00):
    /dev/video1
    /dev/video2
    /dev/video3
    /dev/video4
    /dev/video5
    /dev/video6
    /dev/video7
    /dev/video8

ipu6 (pci:pci0000:00):
    /dev/media0

Intel MIPI Camera (platform:v4l2loopback-000):
    /dev/video0




I have the exact same setup and had the same problem.
You need to have a v4l2-relayd service running that forwards the gstreamer output to /dev/video0.
Running sudo gst-launch-1.0 icamerasrc ! v4l2sink name=v4l2sink device=/dev/video0 does that.
I wrote a small systemd service, so that v4l2-relayd is automatically run after login:
[Unit]
Description=Webcam Streaming

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "gst-launch-1.0 icamerasrc ! v4l2sink name=v4l2sink device=/dev/video0"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

